# Merge sort returns an ArrayList comprised of multiple duplicates of the first entry rather than a sorted ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, mergesort

Calling my Merge sort method on an `ArrayList` of data objects returns an `ArrayList` entirely comprised of the first entry in the original `ArrayList` (the original had 9k separate entries, while the 'sorted' one had 9k duplicates of the first entry of the original).

I've gone over the code but can't seem to spot why. The function operates on an `ArrayList` of `JsonObject` from javax, and the sorting criteria is a field within said `JsonObject`. It's supposed to compare the strings of said field and sort them.

```
public void sortDataObjects(String identifier, ArrayList<JsonObject> both) {
    ArrayList<JsonObject> left = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<JsonObject> right = new ArrayList<>();
    int size = both.size();
    int midpoint = size / 2;

    if (size == 1) {
        return;
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < midpoint; i++) {
            left.add(both.get(i));
        }
        for (int i = midpoint; i < size; i++) {
            right.add(both.get(1));
        }

        sortDataObjects(identifier, left);
        sortDataObjects(identifier, right);

        mergeSortHelper(identifier, left, right, both);
    }
}

public void mergeSortHelper(String identifier, ArrayList<JsonObject> left, ArrayList<JsonObject> right, ArrayList<JsonObject> both) {
    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = 0;
    int bothIndex = 0;

    while (leftIndex < left.size() && rightIndex < right.size()) {
        if ((left.get(leftIndex).getString(identifier).compareTo(right.get(rightIndex).getString(identifier))) < 0) {
            both.set(bothIndex, left.get(leftIndex));
            leftIndex++;
        } else {
            both.set(bothIndex, right.get(rightIndex));
            rightIndex++;
        }
        bothIndex++;
    }

    if (leftIndex >= left.size()) {
        // The left ArrayList has been use up...
        for (int i = rightIndex; i < right.size(); i++) {
            both.set(bothIndex, right.get(i));
            bothIndex++;
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = leftIndex; i < left.size(); i++) {
            both.set(bothIndex, left.get(i));
            bothIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your bug is here:

```
for (int i = midpoint; i < size; i++){
    right.add(both.get(1));
}
```

This does not put the second half of the original list into `right`.

Answer (score 1):

The `right` array is not initialized properly, the assignment `right.add(both.get(1));` is incorrect: there is a typo that can easily go unnoticed, `1` for `i`.

It would also be advisable handle empty arrays correctly too.

Here is a corrected version:

```java
public void sortDataObjects(String identifier, ArrayList<JsonObject> both) {
    int size = both.size();

    if (size > 1) {
        ArrayList<JsonObject> left = new ArrayList<JsonObject>();
        ArrayList<JsonObject> right = new ArrayList<JsonObject>();
        int midpoint = size / 2;

        for(int i = 0; i < midpoint; i++) {
            left.add(both.get(i));
        }
        for (int i = midpoint; i < size; i++) {
            right.add(both.get(i));
        }
        sortDataObjects(identifier, left);
        sortDataObjects(identifier, right);
        mergeSortHelper(identifier, left, right, both);
    }
}
```